# Make Bash Tab Autocomplete match like "Contains" in all possible files instead of "Starting With"

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, zsh, autocomplete

I want to make the bash autocomplete on `TAB` behave a little like oh-my-zsh.

I already added ignore case and cycle through all possibilities on each tab.

Now currently if I have a folder in directory named `LinuxCommands` and I write `Comm+TAB` it doesn't match `LinuxCommands` folder.

Is there any way to change the behavior of bash to match the keyword entered with folder and file names based on "`filename contains keywords`" instead of the current behavior "`filename starts with keywords`"?

I don't think it matters as it's all bash. But just in case it does, I'm using MacOS Sierra.

***Update 1***

Currently I have this code in my `~/.bashrc` for this modification

```
    _cd_completion() {
        mapfile -t COMPREPLY < <(ls -d */ | grep "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}")
    }
    complete -F _cd_completion cd

    # If ~./inputrc doesn't exist yet, first include the original /etc/inputrc so we don't override it
    if [ ! -a ~/.inputrc ]; then echo '$include /etc/inputrc' > ~/.inputrc; fi
    # Add option to ~/.inputrc to enable case-insensitive tab completion
    bind 'set completion-ignore-case On'

    bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous on'
    bind 'TAB:menu-complete'
```

It accomplishes the tasks individually. But the integral performance is weird. It autocompletes and then cycles through the contents of the same folder after autocompleting which is one level behind on directory.

Ex: if I have Folder1, Something2 and NewFolder3 and if I press `cd F+TAB` then it shows `> cd Folder1/` and then when I press `TAB` again, it shows `> cd Folder1/Something2` and the next time shows `> cd Folder1/NewFolder3` and keeps cycling through the previous level folders like this.

Answer (score 5):

You can add your own bash_completion rules in `~/.bashrc`
add the folowing code to the file:

```
_cd_completion() {
    mapfile -t COMPREPLY < <(ls -d */ | grep "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}")
}
complete -F _cd_completion cd
```

next you have to restart your terminal or enter the next command: `source ~/.bashrc`

If you want to make it system-wide you can also add the rules to bash_completion inside the file /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/cd

Comment: It says `-bash: mapfile: command not found`

Comment: apparently macOs runs behind on bash version. http://clubmate.fi/upgrade-to-bash-4-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: Used that. And it worked. But facing some issue now. Updated the question with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case helped comment out `TAB: menu-complete` in my `~/.inputrc`, so it looks now:

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\e[C": forward-char
"\e[D": backward-char
set match-hidden-files off
set page-completions off
set completion-query-items 350
set completion-ignore-case on
set colored-stats on
set show-all-if-ambiguous off
set enable-bracketed-paste on
set history-size -1
set menu-complete-display-prefix on

#set bell-style none
#TAB: menu-complete
```